# Close window in node-webkit using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node-webkit

How to close window using AngularJs and node-webkit ? I don't want to use funcionality of windows.close() when navigathing through app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you'll want to use node-webkit's native API to access the window Object
... [node-webkit Window API](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Window)

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var win = gui.Window.get();

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    $scope.close = function() {
       win.close(); 
    };
}]);
```